# best zpool properties and features for hdd zfs

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, raid

**which properties and features should I use for the **normal** and **mirror** pool? (on ZFS on Linux on Ubuntu/Arch/Manjaro)**

I have two 4TB HDDs and I want to create two pools:

1. **normal** (RAID0): with first 500G of 1st drive and 500G of 2nd drive (~1TB in total)
2. **mirror** (RAID1): with rest of 1st drive and rest of 2nd drive (~3.5TB in total)

the **normal** pool will be used as an all-purpose working storage, it will probably have one dataset and should be as fast as possible,
it will store temporary data like large NN datasets for training

the **mirror** pool will be used as reliable, archive storage, it will have two datasets

1. **snap**: which will receive snapshots of /home directory from another pool from an SSD
2. **vault**: which will store valuable data

*personally I'm thinking of zstd compression for mirror and lz4 compression for normal*

**what do those properties do, (they are applied to **bpool** and **rpool** on the SSD, as suggested in ZOL guide for Ubuntu)**

```
ashift=12  
acltype=posixacl  
canmount=off  
normalization=formD  
relatime=on  
xattr=sa  
dnodesize=auto
```

Comment: *the **normal** pool will be used as an all-purpose working storage, it will probably have one dataset and should be as fast as possible, it will store temporary data like large NN datasets for training* has totally different requirements from something like *the **mirror** pool will be used as reliable, archive storage*  Two large, slow 5,400-rpm SATA drives in a mirror are good for your **mirror** pool, but totally unsuited for your **normal** pool, and sharing the drives between the two pools makes this design even more unsuited for something that "should be as fast as possible".

Comment: As fast as possible does not have to be actually fast compared to an SSD.

Comment: The question was asked two weeks ago, so I proceeded to set up the configuration as described above. Despite lower raw transfer rates (350-800 MB/s highly depending on the data as LZ4 compression is enabled), the normal pool performs quite comparable to an SSD, in everyday tasks like Steam Game Library. (it might be partially because these HDD's are NAS, and I heard that most workloads and almost all games have a little to no benefit from SSD's faster than SATA3)